# Javascript unable to find 'src' attribute for previewed image

Tags: javascript, html, image, file

I am using JavaScript to create an img element when a form is submitted:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {

const imgBox = document.getElementById('image-box');

imgDis = document.createElement('img')
imgDis.setAttribute('id','image-display')
imgBox.appendChild(imgDis);
const img = document.getElementById('img');



    let file = imgInput.files[0];
if(file){
    const read = new FileReader();

    read.addEventListener('load', function() {
        imgDisplay = document.getElementById('image-display');
        imgDisplay.setAttribute("src", this.result);
    });

    read.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

As you can see I am setting the attribute "src" of the image to the result property of the fileReader containing the url.

```
imgDisplay.setAttribute("src", this.result);
```

However, when I later try to use getAttribute to get this specific url...

```
let imgWeb = document.getElementById('image-display');
let imgSrc = imgWeb.getAttribute('src');
console.log(imgSrc);
```

It returns null...

I have tried:

1. Seeing if it is able to get the id from the image... which it is able to...

```
let imgSrc = imgWeb.getAttribute('id');
```

returns...

```
image-display
```

2. I have also examined the image element itself to check that the src was in fact being assigned

```
console.log(imgWeb);
```

returns...

```
<img id="image-display" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j…/bYFwvW+oH/wAvZn3kHWKuZf/Z">
```

Research has led me to believe that it could be a security feature that prevents JS from knowing the files path (this is understandable). Though whether or not this is the problem i am unsure.

Is there another way of accessing the source of the image that is being previewed?

The HTML for the image input is:

```
 <form class="form-right" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form" method="post">
     <div class="input-field">
            <p class="label">Select Image</p>
            <input name="comp-img" type="file" class="browser-default input-right" id="img-input"> 
            </div>

<input type="submit" class="input-right" id="submit-right">
            </form>
```

The HTML for where the image will be appended is:

```
<div class="card-image" id="image-box"></div>
```

REPREX:

```
<html>
  <body>

<form class="form-right" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form" method="post">
<div class="input-field">
<input name="comp-img" type="file" class="browser-default input-right" id="img-input"> 
            </div>
   <input type="submit" class="input-right" id="submit-right">


            </form>
            <div class="card-image" id="image-box"></div> 
          </body>
  </html>
<script>

let form = document.getElementById('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  const imgInput = document.getElementById('img-input');
console.log('he');
const imgBox = document.getElementById('image-box');

imgDis = document.createElement('img')
imgDis.setAttribute('id','image-display')
imgBox.appendChild(imgDis);
const img = document.getElementById('img');



    let file = imgInput.files[0];
    if(file){
        const read = new FileReader();
    
        read.addEventListener('load', function() {
            imgDisplay = document.getElementById('image-display');
            imgDisplay.setAttribute("src", this.result);
        });
    
        read.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
let imgWeb = document.getElementById('image-display');
let imgSrc = imgWeb.getAttribute('src');
console.log(imgWeb);
console.log(imgSrc);
e.preventDefault();
});</script>
```

Comment: _“could be a security feature that prevents JS from knowing the files path”_ - your image source is a Data URI, so there is no real actual file system path that could need any sort of “protection” at this point. // Can you present the whole thing as a proper [mre], please, instead of independent snippets?

Comment: @CBroe I added a minimal reproducible example at the bottom of the code.

Comment: You are trying to read the image source, before it was even set. The FileReader operation is asynchronous. You need to access the image source _inside_ the `load` callback function.